# Nice output for exception of exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, exception, ocaml

In OCaml it's possible to let an exception carry another exception:

```
exception Example of exn
```

But when this exception is raised from another module, the output looks something like this:

```
Module.Example(_)
```

Any solution to this? What I want is of course

```
Module.Example(Not_found)
```

or similar.

I have this problem in OUnit, so it's not possible for me to solve it with a well-placed `try ... with`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended solution is to not carry exceptions around as values unless there is a need to re-raise them later.

There is however a way to print the details of exceptions that matter to you by registering your own exception printer. This is done as follows:

```
(* File exn.ml *)

exception Example of exn

let () =
  Printexc.register_printer (function
    | Example e ->
        Some ("Example(" ^ Printexc.to_string e ^ ")")
    | _ ->
        None
  )

let () =
  try raise (Example (Example Not_found))
  with e ->
    Printf.eprintf "Uh oh: %s\n%!" (Printexc.to_string e)
```

Compile and run:

```
$ ocamlopt -o exn exn.ml
$ ./exn 
Uh oh: Example(Example(Not_found))
```

Comment: _Why_ isn't it recommended? Because of the printer problems?

Comment: It just has to do with how you want to use exceptions. I don't know what value there is in catching them AND wrapping them untouched. Either you catch them and translate them into a message that makes more sense to the user of your library, or you let them go through, if they're already in a form that's acceptable to the user.

One satisfying use of exceptions is in our web backend: anywhere in our code we convert errors/exceptions into exceptions corresponding to standard HTTP error statuses. They are caught by the server loop, and other exceptions result in a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the details, but I suspect the name would be printed if it could be retrieved reliably. It is printed from the toplevel in my experiments, but not from compiled code.

One possible thing would be to use `Printexc.to_string` to convert the exception to a string and have `Example` carry a string instead. Or you could have Example carry both the exception and the string.